# My Kotlin code converts Latin alphabet characters to binary code but non-Latin alphabet characters(Amharic, Arabic etc) can't convert

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, data-conversion

Hello everyone my code converts Latin alphabet characters to binary but crashes when i try converting non-Latin alphabet characters. Can you help me so my code can convert every alphabet?

```
fun strToBinary(str: String): String {
    val builder = StringBuilder()

    for (c in str.toCharArray()) {
        val toString = c.code.toString(2) // get char value in binary
        builder.append(String.format("%08d", Integer.parseInt(toString))) // we complete to have 8 digits
    }

    return builder.toString()
}
```

When i try non-Latin characters it gives this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000100011"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at BinaryKt.strToBinary(Binary.kt:6)
    at BinaryKt.main(Binary.kt:41)
    at BinaryKt.main(Binary.kt)
```

Comment: You can't encode non-ASCII characters using 8 bytes per char. To encode Arabic etc. you really need to use one of encoding like `UTF-8`. What do you need this binary for? It is rather rare to perform such encoding manually.

Comment: I'm making an app for text to binary code conversion.

Comment: There are some text to binary conversion apps on playstore that can convert non-Latin characters.

Comment: You need to understand that there is no single way on how to convert text into binary. While converting exactly the same text, you can get multiple different binary results. Depending on what you plan to do with the result, your format may be not at all compatible with the consumer of this binary data. So before you implement this, you really need to decide how do you want to encode the text. If you don't know or you don't care then I suggest using `UTF-8` encoding which is kind of standard. Then I can provide the solution.

Comment: What i want for this app to do is it should convert text to binary and vice versa and share that conversion to whatsapp etc. For example User A should convert "Hello" to binary and send it to User B and User B should convert it back to text using my app.

Comment: Also for binary to text i use this two functions

Comment: fun binaryToString(binary: String): String {
    val chars = CharArray(binary.length / 8)
    var i = 0

    while (i < binary.length) {
        val str = binary.substring(i, i + 8)
        val nb = Integer.parseInt(str, 2)
        chars[i / 8] = nb.toChar()
        i += 8
    }

    return String(chars)
}

fun isBinary(txt: String?): Boolean {
    if (txt != null && txt.length % 8 == 0) {
        for (c in txt.toCharArray()) {
            if (c != '0' && c != '1')
                return false
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly assumed that a character always takes 1 byte. This is only true when using ASCII, but less common characters may take as much as even 4 bytes per char.

I suggest first encoding the whole string into `ByteArray` using `UTF-8` and then converting it byte by byte:

```kotlin
fun strToBinary(str: String) = buildString {
    str.toByteArray().forEach {
        append(it.toUByte()
            .toString(2)
            .padStart(8, '0')
        )
    }
}
```

Note that such encoding takes quite a log of space. Resulting string is at least 8 times longer than the original text. You can use hex encoding to make it 4 times shorter:

```kotlin
fun strToHex(str: String) = buildString {
    str.toByteArray().forEach {
        append(it.toUByte()
            .toString(16)
            .padStart(2, '0')
        )
    }
}
```

Or make it even shorter using `base64` encoding:

```kotlin
fun strToBase64(str: String) = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str.toByteArray())
```

**Update**

To decode the string we basically need to reverse all steps. For example, for decoding from binary we need to chunk the string into 8-chars parts, decode each of them into a single byte, create byte array and then decode into string using `UTF-8`:

```kotlin
fun binaryToStr(binary: String) =
    binary.chunked(8)
        .map { it.toUByte(2).toByte() }
        .toByteArray()
        .decodeToString()
```

Comment: This new strToBinary is exactly what I'm looking for thank you. But I wasn't able to write a counterpart binaryToText  function for it. My function returns some weird characters. Can you help me in this too please?

Comment: I added decoding from binary.

Comment: Again thank you very much. But I have a question. As a newbie to programming I have to ask how do you know the existence of decodeToString() method so you can use it this fast? Isn't this method rather obscure? Is it experience ?

Comment: Short answer: place the cursor in Intellij/Android Studio just after `toByteArray()`, type `.str` like you would need to use some function with "str" in its name and see what functions you get from autocomplete feature. Long answer: Kotlin stdlib provides quite a lot of useful utils for converting one data to another. In `strToBinary()` I used `String.toByteArray()`, so I assumed there has to be the opposite. `toString()` is kind of reserved name for functions in Java/Kotlin, so I searched for another name using autocomplete feature.